# A working linux kernel + gem5 config for FS boot up in x86 SMP

Tags: linux, x86, multiprocessing, x86-64, gem5

I'm trying to bring up a gem5 FullSystem (FS) simulation of Linux kernel 2.6.22.9 (as the binary was provided by gem5) and also with a custom Linux kernel 3.4.112 on a TimingSimpleCPU. While both of these work in a single core x86 FS simulated machine, they fail to boot up in a multi-core simulated machine.

I'm lost on how to even begin debugging. I have tried connecting to the remote gdb port provided by gem5 TimingSimpleCPU for each processor on ports 7000, 7001 and so on. I see that on a dual core boot up, after a point, core 0 gets stuck on schedule() call and core 1 always stays on idle() and never schedules() anything until core 0 also gets stuck on the schedule() call.

What is a proper way to go about debugging gem5 and its compatibility with Linux Kernel for multi core full system boot up on a TimingSimpleCPU X86 arch? I'm thinking there could be issues relating to spinlock support or the APIC.

Answer (score 3):

X86 2 core Linux kernel 5.1, TimingSimpleCPU, gem5 08c79a194d1a3430801c04f37d13216cc9ec1da3 happened to work on this setup: https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/6aa2f783a8a18589ae66e85f781f86b08abb3397#gem5-buildroot-setup-getting-started Boot completes and `cat /proc/cpuinfo` says 2 CPUs.

The final run command was:

```
./run --cpus 2 --emulator gem5 -- --cpu-type TimingSimpleCPU
```

Everything is specified in that repo, including how to build gem5, the Linux kernel, and how to run them.

Then, with a mere flick of a switch, the same works on aarch64 as well if  you are curious:

```
./run --arch aarch64 --cpus 2 --emulator gem5 -- --cpu-type TimingSimpleCPU
```

I then added the options `--caches --l2cache` as per OP's comment, and now I reproduce the failure, to which I don't have a solution:

```
./run --cpus 2 --emulator gem5 -- --cpu-type TimingSimpleCPU --caches --l2cache
```

Boot hangs, the last terminal message is:

```
pci 0000:00:04.0: legacy IDE quirk: reg 0x1c: [io  0x0376]
```

and a bit above we can see the suspicious message:

```
[Firmware Bug]: CPU1: APIC id mismatch. Firmware: 1 APIC: 0
```

ARM boot with the extra options worked however:

```
./run --arch aarch64 --cpus 2 --emulator gem5 -- --cpu-type TimingSimpleCPU --caches --l2cache
```

However, I later tried with more cache options:

```
/run --arch aarch64 --emulator gem5 --cpu 2 --run-id 2 -- --cpu-type=HPI --caches --l2cache --l1d_size=64kB --l1i_size=64kB --l2_size=256kB
```

and it also failed as explained at: https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/99180e6616331b7385b09147f11f67962f9facc4#gem5-arm-multicore-hpi-boot-fails ...

How to debug such problems to get things working in general is an extremely difficult problem that requires understanding enough Linux kernel + X86 ISA + gem5, where enough is undefined. This learning process is closely intertwined with enabling just the right log options / focusing on the right part of the code. That setup just happened to work out of "luck".

Comment: Does this setup work with a larger number of cores?

Comment: @HadiBrais don't know, tell me how many do you need, and I test it :-)

Comment: Maybe 8 cores, for example. Have you tried running any of the SPEC CPU benchmarks on this setup? Thanks.

Comment: @HadiBrais 8 core boot worked. I don't have access to SPEC, but I find it very unlikely that it would fail in FS after the Linux kernel booted ;-)

Comment: x264 might be a useful test-case that will load all your CPUs from a single multi-threaded program that starts CPUs * 1.5 threads, and uses mutexes and/or other things to manage them.  (And which defaults to producing deterministic output from a given input video, for the same settings and number of cores.)  You could feed it a series of PNG images.  Or even the same PNG image hardlinked `n` times, although that will make motion search find a hit right away...

Comment: @CiroSantilli I directly built gem5 using the commit you have mentioned and also built Linux kernel v5.1 using a config that's a merge of linux-4.15.config and buildroot-x86_64 config listed in your buildroot repo. Multi core is not coming up on gem5. Could you please share the working kernel config for x86 SMP on gem5?

Comment: @SanthoshKumar everything is contained in the repo. Just to a `./build-linux` there, then go into the `out/linux` folder to find the config. The commands that generate the config will also be shown on stdout, including on `./build-linux --dry-run`.

Comment: @PeterCordes yes, notably x264 is one of the [Parsec bencharmarks](https://github.com/cirosantilli/parsec-benchmark) which many architecture researchers still use.

Comment: @CiroSantilli Have you tried booting up a multicore x86_64 system with l2cache as LLC using gem5's "--caches --l2cache" flag?

I also used your buildroot repo to build gem5 and linux.

gem5 multicore x86_64 with L2Cache + Linux compilation with min config + (jason's gem5 magic config or buildroot x86_64 config) =  does not boot up;

Linux was built using "./build-linux --arch x86_64 --config-fragment linux_config/min --custom-config-file linux_config/buildroot-<reference_version> --linux-build-id min".

Also, I keep seeing this bug on m5term "[Firmware Bug]: CPU1: APIC id mismatch."

Comment: @SanthoshKumar OK, I hadn't tried because I didn't see it mentioned, now I tried and reproduce your failure, at least now we have a reproducible minimal this works that doesn't example, I recommend making that very clear on the question title itself, and always try to provide further reproduction details in general, at least full gem5 CLI and gem5 commit SHA :-)

Comment: @CiroSantilli Thanks for verifying! I would have added a detailed reproduction info but stackoverflow's reply box is too compact & removes formatting & multiline comments! Basically I tried the latest commit on gem5 master branch as of 20th June and also with the commit you had mentioned with and without the L2 cache, with and without the buildroot. I typically run with the following gem5 flags directly "gdb --args ./build/X86/gem5.opt --debug-flags=XYZ configs/example/fs.py --num-cpus=XYZ --disk-image=XYZ.img --kernel XYZ/vmlinux  --cpu-type=TimingSimpleCPU --mem-size=2GB --caches --l2cache"